# Localizing value for Excel cell using spreadsheetgear (.Net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, spreadsheetgear

I am trying to localize the excel cell value using .Net spreadsheetgear dll, When i try to generate the excel i am suing the portugese number format as "[=0]0;###.###,00" which should display the value as 2.265,65 , but this is not happening and it is displaying as 2,265.65( "." is not getting replaced with "," for portugese), Please help me is there any limitations in the excel or do we need to apply anyother number format

Thanks
Sudha

Answer (score 0):

You can control some localization aspects of a workbook such as currency, dates as well as the number group and decimal separators, by passing a particular `CultureInfo` type when creating or opening a workbook file in SpreadsheetGear.  The [Factory.GetWorkbook](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Factory~GetWorkbook.html)(...) and [Factory.GetWorkbookSet](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Factory~GetWorkbookSet.html)(...) methods are overloaded to accept this `CultureInfo` object.  If you do not specify a `CultureInfo` object, SpreadsheetGear defaults to "en-US".

My guess is that your workbook set is currently using "en-US" because you did not specify a Portugese `CultureInfo` type.  Below is an example that should demonstrate how to get your above `NumberFormat` to appear as expected with SpreadsheetGear:

```
// Create a new workbook specifying "pt-BR" CultureInfo
IWorkbook workbook = Factory.GetWorkbook(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"));
IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveWorksheet;
IRange cells = worksheet.Cells;
cells["A1"].NumberFormat = "[=0]0;###.###,00";
cells["A1"].Value = 2265.65;
Console.WriteLine(cells["A1"].Text);
// Output: 2.265,65
```

Comment: I tried .Its not working .I am getting out put as 2,265.65 .Portuguese format is not applying .

Comment: Then please add more specifics to your question, including the code  you've used.