# SpreadSheetGear - How to convert thousand separator with decimal and decimal seperator with comma?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, spreadsheetgear

I've failed to find the NumberFormat to convert the thousand separator with decimal to decimal separator with comma.

```
Worksheet.Range(NumberRange).NumberFormat = "#.##0,00"
```

This is not working for me. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is to tell Excel that your decimal and thousands separators are different, but this will effect the entire application not just a specific cell or worksheet/workbook.

## Code:

```
With Application
    .DecimalSeparator = ","
    .ThousandsSeparator = "."
    .UseSystemSeparators = False
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26300225/233365).

In short, number group and decimal separator characters are controlled by the CultureInfo object used.  You need to specify the correct CultureInfo when first loading the workbook.